# Salesforce1 vs Native app development

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

What is the difference b/w salesforce1 and native app development. And what are the limitations of salesforce1. Is native development became obsolete after the advent of salesforce1 or there are still possibilities to use native mobile sdk of salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the SDK when you want your own experience (e.g. a custom branded app driven by Salesforce data), or when you need additional hardware access (e.g. direct camera access), and you use Salesforce1 when you don't need your own experience (e.g. your users want access to Salesforce), and don't need access to hardware access. Generally, developing for Salesforce1 simply means writing Visualforce pages, while using the SDK you can use different technologies and libraries as you like to create a custom experience. Salesforce1 has limited support for Camera, Microphone, Storage, and other device-specific features, while the SDK typically requires longer development cycles. Realistically, you can consider them two separate tools with different uses, rather than saying that one obsoletes the other.